# HttpGet and pipe chracter

Tags: android, http-get

Is it possible to use the pipe character in a HttpGet?

I have a list of latlngs separated with a pipe e.g. `53.42290885462988,-1.4404749870300293|53.39965626194152,-1.4247894287109375` for use with the google distancematrix, however I get an illegal character error on the pipe character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I get an illegal character error on the pipe character.
```

You need to `encode the | (Pipe Charcter)`

So use `URLEncoder.encode("|","UTF-8");`

[Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html)